# consulta con nodejs y sequelize

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sequelize.js

Necesito realizar una consulta con Sequelize que combine los datos de "codes" y "languages" con un intermediario codeslanguages

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const Codes = require('../models/codes')
const Languages = require('../models/languages');
const CodesLanguages = require('../models/codeslanguages');

exports.codes = async(req, res) =>{
        const result = await Codes.findAll({
                limit: 20,
                include: [
                  {
                    model: CodesLanguages,
                    as: 'CodesLanguages',
                    attributes: [],
                    include: [
                      {
                        model: Languages,
                        as: 'Language',
                        attributes: ['LANGUAGE_ID', 'LANGUAGE_TITLE', 'LANGUAGE_PATH'],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
        });

        res.render('codes', {
        pageName : 'Codes',
        codes: result
        });

}
```

**Mi tabla:**

Tabla codes

| CODE_ID | CODE_TITLE  | CODE_DESC | CODE_CODE |

Tabla languages
| LANGUAGE_ID | LANGUAGE_TITLE | LANGUAGE_PATH |

Tabla codes_languages
| ID_CODELANGUAGE | CODE_ID (relacion en tabla codes) | LANGUAGE_ID (relacion en tabla languages) |

Comment: Hola Fabian, te aconsejo revisar [Advanced M:N Associations > Aliases and custom key names](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/#aliases-and-custom-key-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrias que definir en tu tabla lo siguiente

```
Code.belongsToMany(Category, { through: 'codes_languages ' });
Lenguaje.belongsToMany(Product, { through: 'codes_languages ' });
```

Con esto ya se hace tu asosacion de muchos a muchos, no hay necesidad de definir o crear un archivo para la tabla `codes_languages`, si requieres definir las llaves foraneas, tendira que ser en el mismo `belongsToMany` en sus opciones, pero esto lo puedes ver en la [documentación](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/#aliases-and-custom-key-names)